# WPF MVVM open view depending on the type of object

Tags: wpf, mvvm

For example, I have a program for editing creature's parameters. Each entity has an id and a name property. Also every entity has its own unique parameters. For editing additional parameters I created 2 views How could I place a UserControl instead of a comment and destroy a previous if it was?

```
class Entity {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

class Ant : Entity {
    public bool HasWings { get; set; }
    public int BodyColor { get; set; }
    //...
}

class Cat : Entity {
    public bool HasWool { get; set; }
    public int EyesColor { get; set; }
    //...
}
```

And the view's code:

```
<Window xmlns=...>
    <StackPanel>
        <TextBox Text="{Binding Id}" />
        <TextBox Text="{Binding Name}" />
        <!-- Place for UserControl -->
    </StackPanel>
</Window>

<UserControl ...>
    <StackPanel>
        <Checkbox IsChecked="{Binding HasWings}" />
        <TextBox Text="{Binding BodyColor}" />
    </StackPanel>
</UserControl>

<UserControl ...>
    <StackPanel>
        <Checkbox IsChecked="{Binding HasWool}" />
        <TextBox Text="{Binding EyesColor}" />
    </StackPanel>
</UserControl>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a `ContentControl` and data templates instead of `UserControl`s. The `ContentControl` will show the appropriate data template for the given type and responds to data context changes.

```
<Window xmlns=...>
    <StackPanel>
       <TextBox Text="{Binding Id}" />
       <TextBox Text="{Binding Name}" />
       <ContentControl Content="{Binding}">
          <ContentControl.Resources>
             <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:Ant}">
                <StackPanel>
                   <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding HasWings}" />
                   <TextBox Text="{Binding BodyColor}" />
                </StackPanel>
             </DataTemplate>
             <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:Cat}">
                <StackPanel>
                   <Checkbox IsChecked="{Binding HasWool}" />
                   <TextBox Text="{Binding EyesColor}" />
                </StackPanel>
             </DataTemplate>
          </ContentControl.Resources>
       </ContentControl>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```